Dice Roll Simulation (Permutation Approach)
This is a question on leetcode. I'm aware it's efficiently a dynamic programming question, but I wanted to try a different approach to really exercise my understanding of data structures and algorithms.
Here's the question:

A die simulator generates a random number from 1 to 6 for each roll.
You introduced a constraint to the generator such that it cannot roll
the number i more than rollMax[i] (1-indexed) consecutive times.
Given an array of integers rollMax and an integer n, return the number
of distinct sequences that can be obtained with exact n rolls. Since
the answer may be too large, return it modulo 10^9 + 7.
Two sequences are considered different if at least one element differs
from each other.
Example 1:
Input: n = 2, rollMax = [1,1,2,2,2,3] Output: 34 Explanation: There
will be 2 rolls of die, if there are no constraints on the die, there
are 6 * 6 = 36 possible combinations. In this case, looking at rollMax
array, the numbers 1 and 2 appear at most once consecutively,
therefore sequences (1,1) and (2,2) cannot occur, so the final answer
is 36-2 = 34. Example 2:
Input: n = 2, rollMax = [1,1,1,1,1,1] Output: 30 Example 3:
Input: n = 3, rollMax = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
Output: 181

Here's my intuition for my permutation approach below:
Unpack rollmax and create an expanded list of what the possible die choices could be. For example, if rollmax == [1,1,2,2,2,3], your expanded list would be – [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6]. Then I ran a permutation on this expanded list and used a set to eliminate duplicates. Then I returned the size of the set. In my head this should work but I’m not sure why it doesn’t.
I pass the first two example cases but I fail the third and return 166 instead of 181
def dieSimulator(self, n: int, rollMax: List[int]) -> int:
        def permutation(partial, expanded_list, used):
            nonlocal result_set
            if len(partial) == n:
                print(partial)
                result_set.add(tuple(partial[:]))
                return

            for i in range(len(expanded_list)):
                if not used[i]:
                    used[i] = True
                    partial.append(expanded_list[i])
                    permutation(partial, expanded_list, used)
                    used[i] = False
                    partial.pop()

        # unpack list
        expanded_list = [i + 1 for i, val in enumerate(rollMax) for _ in range(val)]
        
        result_set = set()
        used =  [False]*len(expanded_list)
        permutation([], expanded_list, used)
        return len(result_set)

Any ideas why my above solution doesn't work and how I can tweak it to work? PS: I've solved it correctly using dynamic programming, but I just want to know why this doesn't work and how I can get it to.

the constraint is not on having maximum count of a number, but on consecutive rolls of the number. for example, when you get permutation from the expanded list [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6], it will be missing many valid cases. for instance {1,2,1} is valid but will not be considered in your implementation

why the SHOUTING?

Thanks @Stillalearner. I completely glossed over the implication of 'consecutively' in the question. I guess these are the reasons people fail interviews lol
